# Fixing error in deleted migration and table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sqlite

I'm trying to update my heroku database.  The problem: I created an old model & table that we no longer need. That table had previously been migrated to a production server (along with other changes).  I did a destroy of the model using:

```
rails destroy model ReallyLongModelName
```

That also deleted the migration that created the table.
Later, I created a migration to drop that table.

```
class Drop_ReallyLongTableName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table :really_long_table_name
  end
end
```

I'm now getting a couple of errors.

**First error:**

When trying to migrate the database to the production version of the application, I get this error.

```
Input string is longer than NAMEDATALEN-1 (63)
```

I'm not sure how to go back and edit the name to avoid the long name, so that it clears

**Second error:**

When trying to rollback the Drop_ReallyLongTableName migration, its aborts the rake because

```
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: really_long_table_name
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running this from your Terminal/console:

```
heroku run console
ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:table_name)
```

The migration is the way to go but this might be worth a try to see if the table even exists any more (since your second error message seems to indicate that it is no longer there).

Also, and for what it's worth, you can add conditional logic to your DB migrations should you need to in the future

```
def change
  drop_table :table_name if self.table_exists?("table_name")
end
```